# Is there an osx equivalent of pepakura?

Tags: macos

Title says it all, I'm looking for an osx version of or something similar to [Pepakura Designer](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Dunreeb cutout](http://www.dunreeb.com/3dplugins/) (found via [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/pepakura-designer/)) -- however it seems to be a plugin for Autodesk Maya. You might not be ready to spend $3,495 for Maya just to run this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Maya Trial version costs $0, so together with the Cutout demo version, you can try out for free.

Also, if you are a student, you can get maya for free, check out

http://students.autodesk.com/

Somewhere I read that if one is out of work temporarily, Autodesk has a special campaign for those people, and one also gets many of their software products for free.

So there are lots of possibilities, you just have to know them.

Comment: I think the the student deal works for an year, but the student bundle license has a low price compared to the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Pepakura works with [Wine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darwine/) on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a native solution on Mac OSX to build papercrafts from 3d models: DunreebCutout

https://itunes.apple.com/app/dunreebcutout/id963592540

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Just FYI, you answered a very old question, and the site standards have tightened a bit since that question was posted.  Questions requesting software recommendations are off-topic (although it's OK to provide them in answers).  For future reference, answers should provide actionable solutions, so just linking to a product is sometimes seen as spam.  Explain why it's a good solution and better, show how to use it to solve the problem.  Good advice on how to recommend software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.